# How to output a php variable from a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

There is a variable `$name` in mysql table. This variable contains the name of the site.

How should I display it so that the value of this variable is displayed? When I try to output, the variable is displayed as plain text.

If I try to enclose it in braces as an alternative output, it produces an error:

> Notice: Undefined variable.

Here is my code:

```
$db=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'demo');
mysqli_query($db, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$tb_var=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM var");
$var=mysqli_fetch_assoc($tb_var);
echo ${$var['name']};
```

Mysql code:

```
INSERT INTO `var` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, 'My site name $name');
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have just a variable. You have text that you expect to be handled as a PHP double-quoted string literal, which is close enough to evaluating external input as code to be worried.

You may want to switch to good old [...printf()](http://php.net/sprintf) format codes:

```
INSERT INTO `var` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, 'My site name %s');
```

```php
printf($var['name'], 'Acme Corporate Site');
```

And, if in HTML context:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(sprintf($var['name'], 'Acme Corporate Site'));
```

[Online demo](https://3v4l.org/niWX1)